# spring cloud is failing when I try to mock sleuth in unit tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am facing some error when I try to mock objects like Tracer and Span in unit tests if I use Dalston.SR3 or Dalston.Release versions, but this problem doesn't happen if I use Camden.SR6 or Camden.SR7 versions.

Find an example code [here](https://github.com/fjmpaez911/spring-cloud-sleuth-error)

Microservice **msvc-a** is using Dalston version and has two test classes, where only is failing the class where I am trying to mock the Tracer and the Span objects.

Microservice **msvc-b** is using Camden version and has the same test classes.

At the same time, I can't understand this situation when I am in debug mode in STS and why I can't see any error trace or something like that... only a NullpointerException.

[image]

```html
public class AbstractSpanAccessorTest {

    @MockBean
    private Tracer tracer;

    @MockBean
    private Span span;

    private Random random = new Random();

    @Before
    public void mockSpan() {
        long id = createId();
        Span spanMock = Span.builder().name("mock").traceId(id).spanId(id).build();
        doReturn(spanMock.traceIdString()).when(span).traceIdString();
        doReturn(span).when(tracer).getCurrentSpan();
        doReturn(span).when(tracer).createSpan(anyString());
    }

    private long createId() {
        return random.nextLong();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace or sth? Currently you're showing in the screenshot a situation in which no NPE can be thrown since response can't be null. Also what does it mean that you're trying to mock Sleuth? Please show your test and show which line is causing the NPE to be thrown.

Comment: Hi, you have a link above for the sample code (https://github.com/fjmpaez911/spring-cloud-sleuth-error).

There is no trace available but you can try to run the unit test for both microservices and see what is happening.

In the real scenario I need to mock the Tracer and Span because I don't want to have errors when some code like this is executed in the unit test (String traceIdString = spanAccessor.getCurrentSpan().traceIdString();)

Comment: Hi i understand that I have it but you didn't even write how to run it or test it. You didn't point to any classes etc Please provide the details I asked for. Otherwise I won't be able to help you  :/

Comment: Ok, sorry. you can face the problem if you run the test (ServiceTest2.java and ServiceTest.java) classes

Comment: In looking through the code and those tests are integration tests not unit tests. Also I don't see any mocking. Can you show me where you mock that code?

Comment: public class ServiceTest2 extends AbstractSpanAccessorTest...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153144/discussion-between-francisco-jose-martinez-paez-and-marcin-grzejszczak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. The correct way to mock the Span is:

```
 @Before
 public void mockSpan() {
     long id = createId();
     span = Span.builder().name("mock").traceId(id).spanId(id).build();
     doReturn(span).when(tracer).getCurrentSpan();
     doReturn(span).when(tracer).createSpan(anyString());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tracer wouldn't mock at all with Finchley.SR2 so I ended up with this:

```
Tracing tracing = Tracing.newBuilder().build();
Tracer tracer = tracing.tracer();
```